# How to make the progress bar percent centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem is the percent `100%` is not exactly in the center. I tried spacing it in the JavaScript, but it's not working.

Current output: http://jsfiddle.net/GZSH6/53/

> [image]

JavaScript:

```
var progress = setInterval(function () {
    var $bar = $('.bar');

    if ($bar.width() >= 550) {
        clearInterval(progress);
        $('.progress').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $bar.width($bar.width() + 55);
    }
    $bar.text($bar.width() / 5.5 + "%  ");
}, 800);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GZSH6/57/)

**jQuery**

```
var progress = setInterval(function () {
    var $bar = $('.bar');

    if ($bar.width() >= 520) {
        clearInterval(progress);
        $('.progress').removeClass('active');
        $bar.text("100%");        
    } else {
        $bar.width($bar.width() + 50);
        $bar.text($bar.width() / 5 + "%");
    }

}, 800);
```

**CSS**

```
.bar{
   max-width:520px;    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="width: 590px;text-align:left;text-indent:202px" class="bar">107.27272727272727%</div>
```